# How to extract a substring depending on a specified char using Groovy

Tags: string, groovy

I need to extract part of the name of a folder.  I have this code for each of the folders

```
import groovy.io.FileType
def dirs = []
def currentDir = new File('c:\\CompilationStaging')
currentDir.eachFile FileType.DIRECTORIES, {
    dirs.add( 'C:\\CompilationStaging\\'+it.name)
    println( it.name)
}
dirs.sort() 
def list = dirs.reverse()
```

This gets me a list of folders, in a specific format:

- 2013.28.08.14.08.16_Debug_Value1
- 2013.28.08.14.08.16_Release_Value2
- 2013.28.08.14.18.36_Debug_Value3

I need to get for each `it.name` only the last part of the name (value1, value2, value3)
thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
println( it.name.split( '_' )[ -1 ].toLowerCase() )
```

Comment: I am confirmed I am slow today. Just before posting, I refreshed and saw your answer matching with mine except lower case :), so I had to tweak. :P

Answer (score 2):

If last part will always be after a '_' character then use the `[]` operator as with lists (which is `getAt()` method):

```
it.name[it.name.lastIndexOf('_')+1..-1]
```

Or using regex

```
def regex = /.*(Value\d+$)/
def matcher = (it.name =~ regex)
println matcher[0][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Also try

```
it.name.reverse().takeWhile{it != /_/}.reverse()
```